# Why is this FigureCanvasTkAgg "Tk widget" has annotations and legend outside of view? How to bring them in view?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I wanna place a **pie chart** on my Tkinter GUI such that the legend and the labels never reach outside of the displayed widget. Currently, my legend and some of the labels are not shown in full.

This is the code I have:

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

#GUI code
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Test App")

canvas = tk.Canvas(window,width=1200,height=600)
canvas.grid(columnspan=2,rowspan=4)

figure, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.pie([2,3,6], labels=["Cat","Dog","Leopardddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"], normalize = True)
axes.legend(["Cat","Dog","Leopardddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"],bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1),fontsize=8)

figCanvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=window)
figCanvas.draw()
figCanvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10) #place chart on the tkinter grid

window.mainloop()
```

I do not want to hardcode something like this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5), dpi=100)
```

Because the length of my labels and the size (both height and width) of my legend may change every time the user opens the application.

Any ideas?

Comment: One thing that works but is not very elegant is to use savefig with bbox_inches="tight", save the image to disk and then load it back into the application to be displayed on the GUI. I hate this solution. Surely there must be something similar to bbox_inches="tight" when working with figures? I cannot find it though

Comment: As an alternative approach, I could perhaps calculate the figsize every time? I have tried but not sure how. Any ideas?